# Lazy json data fetching with JS and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I've been looking for a way to lazy load JSON data from an API (since I'm making about 5+ API calls a page) 
and I found this: https://github.com/rpnzl/jquery-lazyjson/tree/v1.0

Seem like a nice class but since I'm using PHP all over my website and the call made by this class is with JavaScript, I have no idea how to combine it with my PHP code to make my website loads "by parts".

My goal is to load fast what's possible, then load dynamically each API call one by one to make website runs smoother.

I would like to hear any ideas for handling multiple API calls and fetching the data dynamically.

This is how I'm fetcing my data right now. all PHP and about 7 seconds of loading:

```
    //Get the match!
    $matches = $data->getMatchHistory($playerId,$characterId); //Returns an array of each match found
    if ($matches == 0)
    {
    //Todo when user not in game
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><h2>We\'re sorry..<br/>There are no matches for this player with '.$playerId.'</div>';
        } else {
            for($i=0;$i<sizeof($matches)-1;$i++)
            {
                $match[$i] = new Match();
                $match[$i]->matchId = $matches[$i]['matchId'];
                $match[$i]->charName = $data->getCharacterName($matches[$i]['character']);
                $match[$i]->stats = $data->getMatchStats($match[$i]->matchId); // Makes another API call and returns the match statistics. One Match = 2 API calls
            }
            ?>
            <h2><?=$playerName?> Match History</h2>
            <?php           
            for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($matches)-1;$i++)
            {
?>
<!--ALOT OF HTML,CSS, AND data fetching this way:-->
<?=matches[$i]->someData;?>

<?php
            }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might as well use PHP to decode and get JSON from API calls.

```
$JSON = file_get_contents("API-URL.json");
```

If we know that the file_get_contents returns a page to a variable (in this case, a JSON string), we can then decode the received JSON using PHP.

```
$Array = json_decode($JSON, 1);
```

Let's say you've got a json string of `{"playerid": 1298134, "gender": "male"}`, you could access these via `$Array["playerid"]` and `$Array["gender"]`, and they would return the variable.

The same goes if you have a array inside the JSON, eg `{"playerid": 1298134, "gender": "male", "personal": {"fname": "Kieran", "lname": "Cross"}}` could be accessed as `$Array["playerid"]` and `$Array["personal"]["fname"]`

If you wish to decode the API at the top of your page, quickly, you can easily do

```
$Array = json_decode(file_get_contents("API-Page.json"), 1);
```

You can read more on this [here, on the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: Everything written in your reply has nothing to do with what I need, it's just what I already have. I've been talking about lazy loading - which means loading elements seperately.